# Easy way to rename rails controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rename

Is there an easy way to rename a controller?  The only way I know of is to either do it by hand or generate a new controller move the code over and destroy the old one.  Seems like there has to be a programmatic way to do this.

Comment: I'm not so clear on what the difficulty is... Are you worried about renaming routes and links?

Comment: It is just a lot of work when you have a bunch, I'm looking at moving a lot of my controllers into a namespace for better organization.

Comment: @Andres: a difficult part is moving the database too. RubyMine forgets it when refactoring.

Comment: Manually renaming is the option you have :) IDE's may not help that much

Comment: This question is similar to this [post][1]. 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11924124/how-to-rename-rails-controller-and-model-in-a-project

Answer (score 5):

Some IDE's (like IntelliJ's RubyMine) will let you Refactor -> Rename a file/variable/method etc, although it's not as reliable in a dynamic language like Ruby as it is in a language like Java.

Answer (score 2):

I had just generated a controller and so I did not have an associated model or database table. I decided to just rename all the files and relevant content that was created when I generated the controller. It is not an 'easy' way to rename the controller but I had confidence in my knowledge of what had been created and what I needed to refactor.

There is a good guide on the [ruby on rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-generate) websites that shows what is generated and what you need to edit or you can see what a typical controller generates below:

```
$ bin/rails generate controller Greetings hello
 create  app/controllers/greetings_controller.rb
  route  get "greetings/hello"
 invoke  erb
 create    app/views/greetings
 create    app/views/greetings/hello.html.erb
 invoke  test_unit
 create    test/controllers/greetings_controller_test.rb
 invoke  helper
 create    app/helpers/greetings_helper.rb
 invoke  assets
 invoke    coffee
 create      app/assets/javascripts/greetings.js.coffee
 invoke    scss
 create      app/assets/stylesheets/greetings.css.scss
```

Also, don't forget to edit the contents of the files above, things like descriptions in your assets files, controller class names and module names etc.