# Model named "Type" in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Good Day.

I have a problem with my Model named "Type". The error is:

```
undefined method `all' for ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::Serialization::Type:Class
```

In this particular part of validation:

```
validates :type_id, presence: { message: 'selected is invalid' }, inclusion: { in: 1..Type.all.count }
```

Maybe it's due to reserved names conflict in Rails. But is there a way that Rails will consider this name before I proceed to refactor? (if nothing else to do).

It's really a bad choice for a name but it's too late.

PS.

When I do 'Type.all.count' in rails console, there are no errors that occured.

Comment: why do you want to validate it? i'm assuming it's a FK but then why would you want to validate it? are you letting your user to set it? and Type is a `reserve` word anyways

Comment: `Type` is reserved one in Rails.. DON'T use it..; Change your model name..

Comment: @user2675613 No, it will be populated on select tag but the administrator can add more values to that table. I opt to validate it 'cause I think the items in select tag can be manipulated using Javascript on the client side, and maybe I'm just too paranoid :).

Comment: @ArupRakshit rename is my last resort if there's nothing that can be done about the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ruby's constant lookup is resulting in it finding the "wrong" Type class. Using "::Type" forces ruby to use the top level Type constant.

You should note that this count will be done once only: when the rails instance starts. If new types were to be added, the validation would not take that into account. If a type were ever deleted then it would not allow the last type to be used.

If you have a `type` association then you could do

```
validates_presence_of :type
```

Upon saving it would try and load the corresponding Type object from the database, so saving would fail if there was no such row.

For a really strong guarantee, you could use a foreign key constraint (the foreigner gem adds helpers to rails migrations for this, but you can also just write the sql statement by hand)

Comment: The problem is the Model itself not the column. Anyway, thanks for your response.

Comment: I know. That's why I suggested ::Type.all.count. I was pointing out that this way of validating type_id has its flaws and pointed out some alternatives

Comment: You are so good man! Sorry for the misconception, `::` did the trick! Finally we've got the real solution here. Yes!

Comment: By the way, is `validates_presence_of :type` the proper way of validation instead of `inclusion: {...}`?

Comment: In general there not the same thing no, but here it's a reasonable fit since what you care about is that it is possible to load a Type for that id

Comment: It was a good suggestion! I also found out that it is more appropriate validation to use. Actually, I already implemented it last night :)

Answer (score 3):

[Here](http://bparanj.blogspot.ru/2011/07/reserved-words-in-rails.html) is a list of reserved words in Rails. As you can see, `type` has also been reported to cause problems.

Rails is built over [convention over configuration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration) agreement, so I would suggest just to pick another model name (which is not mentioned in stated blog post).

Take a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11924124/how-to-rename-rails-controller-and-model-in-a-project) to get an idea of what should be done to turn your `Type` model to something else.

In case you are completely sure model name is not the case, you could try to trick around with different validation notations like

`inclusion: { in: 1.upto(Type.all.count).to_a}`

Comment: Due to my negligence, I'm aware that type is a reserved word. I used to have column named 'type' in my table and got problem with it, that's made aware of reserved words. But when I tried to used it in Model name, I never had a problem, but just then (stupid me). I just don't like two words to describe a name for my Model, example document_type, account_type. If nothing else we can do about it, I am ready for Migration and Refactor.

Comment: But when I do 'Type.all.count' in rails console, there are no errors that occured.

Comment: @Charlie In case you are completely sure model name is not the case, you should provide more code from `Type` model. Also you could try to trick around with different validation notations like `inclusion: { in: 1.upto(Type.all.count).to_a}`.

Comment: thank you! that `1.upto` really helped me. I'll post my answer. Fortunately, I found a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, I found a workaround. However, it is not recommended but if you don't want to do Migration and ton's of Refractions, here is my solution (credits to [twonegatives](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1276552/twonegatives)).

in my validation code:

```
inclusion: { in: 1.upto(:type_alias) }
```

then create that method

```
type_alias
```

```
def type_alias
  Type.all.count
end
```