# Class loading error in rails

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I have a class `App` located in `app/models/administration/app.rb`

```
class App < ActiveRecord::Base
    #...
end
```

And a class `App::Type` located in `app/models/administration/app/type.rb`

```
class App
    class Type
        attr_reader :sym, :name
        ALL = [:type1, :type2]
        #...   
    end
end
```

My application is configured to autoload from `app/models/administration` directory

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#...
                            #{config.root}/app/models/administration)
```

When I try to access `App::Type::ALL` from rails console, I get the following error

```
pry(main)> App::Type::ALL
```

> NameError: uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::Type::ALL

Why is there a confusion between `App::Type::ALL` and `ActiveRecord::Type::ALL` and how can I fix it?

Comment: see this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24352603/model-named-type-in-rails

Comment: @eugenioy So you just can't have a class named `Type` in rails?

Comment: Seems it would not be advisable to use that name, though the related answer suggests some workarounds if you really can't use a different name. I would call it AppType and forget about the issue :)