# replace word/variable name in all files of an app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, sublimetext2

In my rails app I have a scaffold `clients` that is already linked to many other files in the app.

Is there a way to replace the word '`client`' with '`guest`' everywhere in the app, without doing it manually?

Comment: You can do this, hopefully, with your editor.  I use `SublimeText` and it has that feature.

Comment: I don't think there's a clean way of doing this, but someone gave a thorough how-to answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11924124/how-to-rename-rails-controller-and-model-in-a-project)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, a simple find-and-replace did the trick.

But you have to be careful with it and do it in a few steps:

1. replace `client` with `guest`
2. replace `Client` with `guest` (case sensitive)

Careful if the plural form is different (like identity-identities)